# JavaScript to jQuery code transformation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simplify this code and convert it into a jQuery statement. Will someone please show me how I can simplify this code using jQuery. This allows the user to select multiple options from a select and show the options chosen in a text area.

```
// JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea
    var opts = document.querySelectorAll('#loc option');

    document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
        for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
            opts[i].selected = true;
        }

        reflectChange();
    });

    document.getElementById('rem').addEventListener('click', function() {
        for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
            opts[i].selected = false;
        }

        reflectChange();
    });

    document.getElementById('loc').addEventListener('change', reflectChange);

    function reflectChange() {
        document.getElementById('selected').value = '';

        for ( var i=0; i<opts.length; i++ ) {
            if(opts[i].selected)
            document.getElementById('selected').value += opts[i].text+'\n';
        }
    }

    // End JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

    // JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
    var opts1 = document.querySelectorAll('#EmployeeName option');

    document.getElementById('add1').addEventListener('click', function() {
        for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
            opts1[i].selected = true;
        }

        reflectChange1();
    });

    document.getElementById('rem1').addEventListener('click', function() {
        for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
            opts1[i].selected = false;
        }

        reflectChange1();
    });

    document.getElementById('EmployeeName').addEventListener('change', reflectChange1);

    function reflectChange1() {
        document.getElementById('selected1').value = '';

        for ( var i=0; i<opts1.length; i++ ) {
            if(opts1[i].selected)
            document.getElementById('selected1').value += opts1[i].text+'\n';
        }
    }

    // End JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you did provide the code, but the purpose is still not clear. What this code does, and what do you expect in the answer in terms of simplification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the purpose of this code isn't clear. The simplicity of the code depends on the use-case, because then only one can decide what to write.

Yet, I have tried to understand and simplify the code with jQuery. Refer to the following snippet:

```js
// JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

// Listens to the changes in #loc. Prepares the selected elements, and sets the result in
// #selected.
$("#loc").change(function() {
  var selected = [];

  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).text());
  });

  $("#selected").val(selected.join("\n"));
});

// Selects all the options, and manually triggers the change() of #loc
$("#add").click(function() {
  var loc = $("#loc");
  loc.find("option").prop("selected", true);
  loc.change();
});

// Deselects all the options, and manually triggers the change() of #loc
$("#rem").click(function() {
  var loc = $("#loc");
  loc.find("option").prop("selected", false);
  loc.change();
});
// End JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

// JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea

// Listens to the changes in #EmployeeName. Prepares the selected elements, and sets the 
// result in #selected1.
$("#EmployeeName").change(function() {
  var selected = [];

  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).text());
  });

  $("#selected1").val(selected.join("\n"));
});

// Selects all the options, and manually triggers the change() of #EmployeeName
$("#add1").click(function() {
  var emps = $("#EmployeeName");
  emps.find("option").prop("selected", true);
  emps.change();
});

// Deselects all the options, and manually triggers the change() of #EmployeeName
$("#rem1").click(function() {
  var emps = $("#EmployeeName");
  emps.find("option").prop("selected", false);
  emps.change();
});
// End JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="selected" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<select id="loc" multiple>
  <option>loc1</option>
  <option>loc2</option>
  <option>loc3</option>
</select>

<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="rem">Remove</button>

<hr>

<textarea id="selected1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<select id="EmployeeName" multiple>
  <option>emp1</option>
  <option>emp2</option>
  <option>emp3</option>
</select>

<button id="add1">Add</button>
<button id="rem1">Remove</button>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly how I need it except when i click submit before anything is chosen and then hit the add buttons it does not register that they were added even though they are highlighted

Answer (score 1):

```
// JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea
var opts = $('#loc option');

$('#add').on('click', function() {
    opts.prop('selected', true)
    reflectChange();
});

$('#rem').on('click', function() {
    opts.prop('selected', false)
    reflectChange();
});

$('#loc').on('change', reflectChange);

function reflectChange() {
    $('#selected').val('');

    opts.each(function(value,ind){
        $('#selected').val($(value).text + '\n');
    });
}

// End JS for Showing Chosen Locations in textarea

// JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
var opts1 = $('#EmployeeName option');

$('#add1').on('click', function() {
    opts1.prop('selected', true);
    reflectChange1();
});

$('#rem1').on('click', function() {
    opts1.prop('selected', false);
    reflectChange1();
});

$('#EmployeeName').on('change', reflectChange1);

function reflectChange1() {
    $('#selected1').val('');

    opts1.each(function(value,ind){
        $('#selected1').val($(value).text + '\n');
    });
}

// End JS for Showing Chosen Associates in textarea
```

Comment: this is not working it shows this in the textbox `function ( value ) {
  return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
   return value === undefined ?
    jQuery.text( this ) :
    this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) );
  }, null, value, arguments.length );
 }
`